# How to cancel Spring timer execution

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I need to cancel Spring timer execution or at least change the execution frequency based on some conditions. Was using both `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean` and `org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask`. Cannot find the way how to do it.

Answer (score 22):

**NOTE**: This is for Spring 3.0+

1. Read [Spring documentation on scheduling tasks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)
2. Use a [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.16.RELEASE_to_3.2.17.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%203.2.17.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) service, such as a [`TimerManagerTaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.16.RELEASE_to_3.2.17.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%203.2.17.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/TimerManagerTaskScheduler.html) or [`ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.16.RELEASE_to_3.2.17.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%203.2.17.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html).
3. Schedule your task by calling some [`TaskScheduler.schedule*()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.16.RELEASE_to_3.2.17.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%203.2.17.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger)) method **and store the returning [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)**.
4. When you want to cancel execution, invoke [`ScheduledFuture.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-). That will stop further invocations of your task. At this time, you can reschedule if you want by calling `TaskScheduler.schedule*()` for your task with different parameters.

Comment: My beans are provisioned in the spring xml file. How I get an instance of the TaskScheduler from there? Are you saying that I need to provision it all in my Java code?

Comment: Just instantiate the TaskScheduler using a `<bean>` element and inject it wherever you want to use it

Comment: Note, the boolean parameter of `cancel()` method is [mayInterruptIfRunning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-)

Answer (score 0):

This is by far not the best solution but if you can't come up with anything else you could always use a boolean that would be checked each time the event is fired and if the boolean is false the run method of the timertask should immediately terminate.

Comment: That's what I actually did. This approach is definitely not preferable as I don't  want to execute task again if some condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to assign an id to the org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean and then retrieve this bean from the application, cast it to Timer and call cancel method on that object.

Comment: `<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" />`
Then you can get myScheduler and `cancel()`.